# animate with relative and absolute div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Please have a look at  http://users.sch.gr/ellhn. By clicking the top links two animations take place: one drags the current content to the left and the second drags the new content to the center of the browser window.

```
 $("#menu_choice4").click(function () {                              
 $('#content_home').animate({ "left": screenwidth }, 1500 );             
 $('#content_main').animate({ "left": screenwidth},1500);   
 $('#content_creations').animate({ "left": screenwidth }, 1500 );            
         setTimeout( function() {pack4()},900);
         function pack4(){
               $('#content_home').hide();
            $('#content_main').hide(); 
                            $('#content_creations').hide();
            var x4=$("body").width()/2;           
                    var y4=$("#content_mail").width()/2;
            $('#content_mail').animate({ 'left': x4-y4}, 1200 );    
         }           
         $('#content_mail').show();          
      });
```

In the above code #menu_choice4 represents the last top link whereas #content_home, #content_main, #content_creations, #content_mail are the divs which include everything except the top links for each choice respectively.I have to give make these divs absolute positioned as for the animation to work correctly (as you may see from the above site). In case I make them relative positioned the animation has problems.

My question is why do they have to be absolute and not relative? What should I do for the animation to work the right way with relative positions? I want to apply Responsive Web Design and I have a lot of problems with absolute positions...
Thank you very much

Comment: Linked page did not load for me...

Comment: A lot of websites that I've seen that have responsive layouts use media queries. This [link](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) was useful for me